# Как задать версию project

Tags: cmake

Как задать версию проекта при запуске команды `cmake`?

есть `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(my_project LANGUAGES CXX)

message("PROJECT_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}")
message("my_project_VERSION_MAJOR=${my_project_VERSION_MAJOR}")
```

пробовал передавать через аргументы:

```
cmake . -Dmy_project_VERSION_MAJOR=2
```

no `project()` сбрасывает эту переменную.
при запуске `cmake` вывод такой:

```
PROJECT_NAME=my_project
my_prject_VERSION_MAJOR=
```

Версия считается через  `git rev-list HEAD | wc -l` поэтому не хочу явно прописывать в `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(my_project VERSION ${VERSION} LANGUAGES CXX)

message("PROJECT_VERSION = ${PROJECT_VERSION}")
message("PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR = ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}")
message("PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR = ${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}")
message("PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH = ${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}")
```

Запуск:

```
cmake . -DVERSION=42.0.1
```